# rowMeans function in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have been trying to run the calculate `rowMeans` within `dplyr`'s `mutate` function, but keep getting errors. Below is an example DATA set and desired RESULT.

```
DATA = data.frame(SITE = c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C"), 
                  DATE = c("1","1","2","2","3","3","3","4","4"), 
                  STUFF = c(1, 2, 30, 40, 100, 200, 300, 5000, 6000),
                  STUFF2 = c(2, 4, 60, 80, 200, 400, 600, 10000, 12000))

RESULT = data.frame(SITE = c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C"), 
                    DATE = c("1","1","2","2","3","3","3","4","4"), 
                    STUFF = c(1, 2, 30, 40, 100, 200, 300, 5000, 6000),
                    STUFF2 = c(2, 4, 60, 80, 200, 400, 600, 10000, 12000),
                    NAYSA = c(1.5, 3, 45, 60, 150, 300, 450, 7500, 9000))
```

The code I have written begins by randomly sampling `STUFF` and `STUFF2`. Then I would like to calculate the `rowMeans` of `STUFF` and `STUFF2` and export the result to a new column. I could accomplish this task using `tidyr`, but would have to redo a larger number of variables. Furthermore I could use the R base package, but prefer to find a solution using the `mutate` function in `dplyr`. Thanks in advance.

```
RESULT = group_by(DATA, SITE, DATE) %>%
  mutate(STUFF=sample(STUFF,replace= TRUE), STUFF2 = sample(STUFF2,replace= TRUE))%>%
  # These approaches return errors 
  mutate(NAYSA = rowMeans(DATA[,-1:-2]))
  mutate(NAYSA = rowMeans(.[,-1:-2])) 
  mutate (NAYSE = rowMeans(.))
```

Comment: I don't know what's happening, but the problem seems to be using `rowMeans` on a grouped dataset. One fix is to put `ungroup() %>%` before the last mutate. Hopefully someone else will have a better solution though.

Comment: @GregF Yes, `ungroup()` is the key here.  But, I think the OP's use `.[,-1:-3]` may be `.[,3:4]`

Comment: A side note: you can write multiple statements into the same "mutate" - just separate the statements by a comma.

Comment: @GregF Yep....`ungroup()` was the key. Thanks. `RESULT = group_by(DATA, SITE, DATE) %>%
  mutate(STUFF=sample(STUFF,replace= TRUE), STUFF2 = sample(STUFF2,replace= TRUE))%>%
  ungroup()%>%
  mutate(NAYSA = rowMeans(.[,-1:-2]))`

Comment: What does `rowMeans(.[, -1:-2])` do? Is the dot a shorthand notation for the data used in the `mutate` function?

Comment: @cbrnr You are correct. I believe the dot is referred to as a pronoun. It represents the data from the previous step. So in the example above, that would be the data that comes out of the 'mutate(STUFF =.... = TRUE)) %>%' line of code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

@GregF Yep....`ungroup()` was the key. Thanks.

Working code

```
RESULT = group_by(DATA, SITE, DATE) %>% 
  mutate(STUFF = sample(STUFF,replace= TRUE), 
         STUFF2 = sample(STUFF2,replace= TRUE)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(NAYSA = rowMeans(.[,-1:-2]))
```

Comment: Using select would be clearer:  `mutate(NAYSA = rowMeans(select(., STUFF, STUFF2)))`

Answer (score 15):

You need the `rowwise` function in `dplyr` to do that. Your data is random (because of sample) so it produces different results but you will see that it works:

```
library(dplyr)
  group_by(DATA, SITE, DATE) %>%
  mutate(STUFF=sample(STUFF,replace= TRUE), STUFF2 = sample(STUFF2,replace= TRUE))%>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(NAYSA = mean(c(STUFF,STUFF2)))
```

Output:

```
Source: local data frame [9 x 5]
Groups: <by row>

  SITE DATE STUFF STUFF2  NAYSA
1    A    1     1      2    1.5
2    A    1     2      2    2.0
3    A    2    30     80   55.0
4    A    2    30     60   45.0
5    B    3   200    600  400.0
6    B    3   300    200  250.0
7    B    3   100    600  350.0
8    C    4  5000  12000 8500.0
9    C    4  6000  10000 8000.0
```

As you see it calculates the rowwise mean per row, according to STUFF and STUFF2

Comment: Correct, but ungrouping and rowMeans would probably be a lot faster (not tested though..)

Comment: @docendodiscimus Thanks docendo. You are probably right, but I haven't tested either.

Answer (score 6):

Now that dplyr has introduced [`across`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/across.html), this can be accomplished with `across` and base R's `rowMeans`.  The following code will take the row-wise average of columns starting with the string "STUFF":

```
DATA %>% 
  mutate(NAYSA = rowMeans(across(starts_with("STUFF"))))
```

Comment: With dplyr 1.1.0+ `across()` with empty `.fns` argument will throw a warning and eventually an error https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2023/02/dplyr-1-1-0-pick-reframe-arrange/. Use `pick()` instead.

Answer (score 2):

rowMeans function needs at least two dimensions
but `DATA[,-1:-3]` is just one row.

```
[1]     2     4    60    80   200   400   600 10000 12000
```

You can get the Result by below code

```
DATA%>%
        group_by(SITE, DATE) %>% 
        ungroup() %>% 
        mutate(NAYSA = rowMeans(.[,3:4]))

  SITE DATE STUFF STUFF2  NAYSA
1    A    1     1      2    1.5
2    A    1     2      4    3.0
3    A    2    30     60   45.0
4    A    2    40     80   60.0
5    B    3   100    200  150.0
6    B    3   200    400  300.0
7    B    3   300    600  450.0
8    C    4  5000  10000 7500.0
9    C    4  6000  12000 9000.0
```

Comment: I think you forgot the sampling part (and without it, the group_by would be unnecessary). Also note that Vesuccio already provided a working solution with ungroup as answer.

Comment: Also, I edited the original question....it now reads `DATA[,-1:-2]`...sorry of the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Another (best?) way of doing this is using `map2_dbl`:

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
DATA %>% 
  mutate(NAYSA = map2_dbl(STUFF, STUFF2, ~mean(c(.x, .y))))
```

Output:

```
  SITE DATE STUFF STUFF2  NAYSA
1    A    1     1      2    1.5
2    A    1     2      4    3.0
3    A    2    30     60   45.0
4    A    2    40     80   60.0
5    B    3   100    200  150.0
6    B    3   200    400  300.0
7    B    3   300    600  450.0
8    C    4  5000  10000 7500.0
9    C    4  6000  12000 9000.0
```