# How do I create a variable that represents the mean of some specified columns?

Tags: r

here is my question: how do I create a variable that represents the mean of specified columns?

Here is an example data frame

```
data ＜- data.frame(x1 = 1:5,             # Create data frame
               x2 = c(3, 1, 7, 4, 4),
               x3 = 5:9,
               x4 = c(7, 4, 6, 4, 9))
```

Now I want to calculate the means of the columns x1, x2, x3 and x4

```
rowMeans(data[ , c("x1", "x2", "x3", "x4")])    # Sum of multiple columns
```

This works, but I want to create a variable that holds this information. So, I do...

```
mutate(data, mean_of_my_rows = rowMeans(data[ , c("x1", "x2", "x3", "x4")]))
```

But this doesn't work either. It shows me what I want, but it does not create the variable "means_of_my_rows" in my dataset. I tried with another approach, like this

```
data <- 
data %>% 
mutate(means_of_my_rows = rowMeans(c("x1", "x2", "x3","x4")))
```

and this gives me the following code of errors

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `means_of_my_rows`.
i `means_of_my_rows = rowMeans(c("x1", "x2", "x3", "x4"))`.
x 'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions
```

I feel like this is a minor error, but what would you guys suggest?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [rowMeans function in dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29083641/rowmeans-function-in-dplyr)

Answer (score 0):

The issue comes with the use of `rowMeans` with use of the pipes (`%>%`). `rowMeans` expects you’ll be giving it a matrix with more than one column. By default, `dplyr` works columnwise so `rowMeans` is only seeing the first element of x1, x2, x3, and x4 so it looks like the dimensions are 1x1. You can refer to the columns within the data you are piping by using `.`:

```r
library(tidyverse)
data %>%
  mutate(means_of_my_rows = rowMeans(.[,c("x1", "x2", "x3", "x4")]))
#>   x1 x2 x3 x4 means_of_my_rows
#> 1  1  3  5  7             4.00
#> 2  2  1  6  4             3.25
#> 3  3  7  7  6             5.75
#> 4  4  4  8  4             5.00
#> 5  5  4  9  9             6.75
```

Or use the `rowwise` function in `dplyr`:

```r
data %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(means_of_my_rows = mean(c(x1, x2, x3, x4)))
#> # A tibble: 5 x 5
#> # Rowwise: 
#>      x1    x2    x3    x4 means_of_my_rows
#>   <int> <dbl> <int> <dbl>            <dbl>
#> 1     1     3     5     7             4   
#> 2     2     1     6     4             3.25
#> 3     3     7     7     6             5.75
#> 4     4     4     8     4             5   
#> 5     5     4     9     9             6.75
```

Or you can avoid `dplyr` and just use base:

```
data$means_of_my_rows <- rowMeans(data[ , c("x1", "x2", "x3", "x4")])
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>